# New-PSDrive as "anonymous" for remote share that has enabled "Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users"

Tags: windows, powershell

How does one connect anonymously to an SMB share in powershell using New-PSDrive?

I've tried omitting the `-Credential` param but this seems to use the currently logged in user. This works when I test using a domain account, however the problem is for normal operation the currently logged in user is a local kiosk user for assigned access that the domain file server does not recognize.

I've also tried using the following, however it prompts for user input. As this is run as a scheduled task for background operation - this is unacceptable.

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential -UserName 'NTAUTHORITY\Anonymous Logon'
New-PSDrive -ErrorAction Stop -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "$RemoteFolder" -Name "$RemoteDriveLetter" -Credential $Credentials -Persist -Scope Global | Out-Null
```

I have enabled the local security policy option on the file server for "Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users".

How do I utilize the "anonymous" user connection with `New-PSDrive`?

-- edit --

I've also tried this

```
$Credentials = [pscredential]::Empty
New-PSDrive -ErrorAction Stop -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "$RemoteFolder" -Name "$RemoteDriveLetter" -Credential $Credentials -Persist -Scope Global | Out-Null
```

However, the output is:

```
>> TerminatingError(New-PSDrive): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The specified network password is not correct"
The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The specified network password is not correct
```

Comment: Are you not able to apply a GPO for kiosk users to allow this?

Comment: The windows "assigned access" creates its own local user account for the application to run as. So the kiosk users are not domain users

Comment: The kiosk application is the "camera" app and I am trying to move the pictures taken to a network fileserver for persistence and ease of access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous mounts use an 'empty' user and password for the credential block so you can do the same.
This works for me and allows file creation on the share:

```
$User = " " # Create 'empty' username
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String " " -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
New-PSDrive -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "$RemoteFolder" -Name "$RemoteDriveLetter" -Credential $Credentials -Persist -Scope Global | Out-Null
```

Comment: Is the username and password supposed to be a single " " space character?

Comment: Yes, when I try with an empty string for either they both throw errors.

Comment: Does `-Credential ([pscredential]::Empty)` work? Note that you don't need to enclose variable references passed as command arguments in `"..."` in PowerShell (even if the variable values happen to contain spaces); e.g., `-Root $RemoteFolder` will do.

Comment: "The specified network password is not correct" when I used `$Credentials = [pscredential]::Empty`. "The user name or password is incorrect" when I use single whitespace string. And a Powershell error if I try to use an empty string

Comment: I have since enabled "Accounts: Guest account status" to Enabled in the local security policy and it now seems to be working with the empty space as you wrote!

Comment: @mklement0 the variables wrapped in quotes was down to my lazy copy & pasting from the original question, thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: I didn't need to enable guest accounts for it to work, though I was logged in as a local administrator.